# When making a library on unix, is anything but "ar rcs" necessary?

Tags: linker, unix-ar

I have a number of source files I want to agglomerate into a `.a` file. I make the library with the command

```
ar rcs libcathat.a thing1.o thing2.o fish.o
```

I then attempt to link to this library with the same compiler I used to make the `.o` files (g++):

```
 g++ -L/path/to/cathat -lcathat seuss.o -o seuss
```

But this produces errors when I try to use functions defined in thing1.cpp (and in theory represented in thing.o) of the form:

```
/path/seuss.cpp:46: undefined reference to `redFishBlueFish(int, char**)'
```

**Is there something else I need to do to a `.a` file to make it possible to link to it?**

Comment: You're missing the red fish and the blue fish!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Fish reference added :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving the linker statements to the end:

```
g++ seuss.o -o seuss -L/path/to/cathat -lcathat
```

If that doesn't work, make sure those symbols are actually in the archive:

```
nm libcathat.a
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you don't need to do anything else on most modern versions of Unix.

On some, mainly older, versions of Unix, it was necessary to use `ranlib` on a library to add a lookup table that allowed the linker to find symbols quickly.  Almost all modern versions of `ar` do this automatically.  Needing `ranlib` is something of a hangover from the 'bad old days' of 7th Edition UNIX™.

---

For some reason which I can't now locate, I was building archives on Mac OS X 10.7.4 with `ranlib` too.  I must have had a reason for doing so, but that reason seems to be irrelevant now — archive libraries seem work OK without `ranlib` on Mac OS X 10.7.4, at least for a single architecture.  I did find a change I made in July 2004 that put `ranlib` back into a `make` program, but the check-in notes don't say why I made the change.  I've updated the rule definition file so it no longer uses `ranlib`.